# Poner un reproductor de vídeo en un componente en Angular 14

Tags: angular, html-video

uso Angular 14, tengo un componente the-player donde quiero poner un reproductor de video al que le pueda llevar dinámicamente el url del vídeo que debe reproducir, ensayé este post:
https://www.positronx.io/angular-video-player-using-ngx-videogular-with-customized-controls-example/

Pero dañó mi app, se quedó haciendo algo de los bundle; tuve que crear una nueva.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en app.component.html

```
source src="./assets/videos/deTodo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

utilizar otros videos mp4

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/390701)